# Bit setting logic in C

Tags: c, arduino, logic, bit

I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind successfully setting a bit in a 32 bit register.  Here is the pseudo-code for the function:

Read the master register,
If the 29th bit `CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0` is not set, set it

```
uint32_t creg;

//read the CREG Master register   
creg = READ_ARC_REG((volatile uint32_t)AR_IO_CREG_MST0_CTRL);

if((creg & (1 << CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0)) == 0){
     creg |= ( 1 << CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0);
     WRITE_ARC_REG(creg, (volatile uint32_t)(AR_IO_CREG_MST0_CTRL));
}
```

If the CREG master register is initially empty, the logic doesn't work as intended.  However, if I fill it with all zeros and a 1 in the 31st bit (1000...0) the logic does work.  I'm not sure if my test condition is incorrect or if it could be something else.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the type of `creg`?

Comment: "if the 29th bit is not set" - why not just set it anyway.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? If you simply want to set a bit, then I wouldn't even bother with the conditional at all, just set it. If it already happens to be set, who cares?

Comment: Your code as written expects `CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0` to be 29, for the 29th bit. Are you sure that this is the case, and that `CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0` isn't 0b00100000000000000000000000000000 for the 29th bit?

Comment: @yano: Extra call of WRITE_ARC_REG can matter, depending on API.

Comment: Never use a cast until you can prove you have to and you understand all implications! The macros you use should already be defined properly (if not get another toolchain, it is bad. And be careful with bitshifting signed integers. Avoid them unless you really know what you do and you have to!

Comment: here is the define statement: `#define     CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0      (29)` and I tried removing the conditional statement so the bit gets set regardless, and using `1L` but I still have the same issue.  The bit won't get set if CREG master is initially empty.

Comment: I know it's a C register, but is it wrong that I'm pronouncing it "Craig" in my head?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use the data type given: uint32_t.  That will guarantee alignment regardless of context.  That is *(factored for clarity, and assuming shift doesn't yield different size-type)*:

```
uint32_t mask = ((uint32_t)1) << CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0;
if((creg & mask) == 0){
     creg |= mask;
     WRITE_ARC_REG(creg, (volatile uint32_t)(AR_IO_CREG_MST0_CTRL));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas towards debugging your issue:

Step 1:  Make sure you actually understand how that register works.  Remember, microcontroller registers may behave differently from memory.  The register may ignore your attempt to write a `1` to a bit until after some other condition is met.  Perhaps that's why it works if you write a `1` to bit 31 first.  What does bit 31 do?

Step 2:  I poked around online and found that the same header that defines `READ_ARC_REG()` and `WRITE_ARC_REG()` may also include the definition for `SET_ARC_BIT()`.  See if you can find and use that.

Step 3:  Make sure what you're trying to write makes sense.  Step through the function in your debugger and/or add some form of printout to display the value you're attempting to write to the register.  Then read the register after doing so and repeat that process.  See if you tried to write the correct value, then see whether that write actually took.  If your code tried to write your desired value to the register but the subsequent read showed that your write didn't change the bit then go back to Step 1 above.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess (I don't do much embedded programming), but according to C standard the number literal `1` has type `int`. In embedded programming `int` can be 16 bits, in which case your left shift will have undefined behaviour, since right operand is too large.

So try using `1L` to make this of type `long`.

Also, as mentioned by Olaf in comments, do not use `(volatile uint32_t)` cast unless you are sure that you need it. Some googling suggests that this is about Arduino 101, and [source code](https://github.com/01org/corelibs-arduino101/blob/master/variants/arduino_101/variant.cpp#L193) I found does use both `READ_ARC_REG` and `WRITE_ARC_REG` without any cast.

```
creg = READ_ARC_REG(AR_IO_CREG_MST0_CTRL);

if((creg & (1L << CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0)) == 0){
     creg |= (1L << CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0);
     WRITE_ARC_REG(creg, AR_IO_CREG_MST0_CTRL);
}
```

Comment: I have removed my volatile casts, casted my '1' integer to a uint32_t and used a mask, but the bit still doesn't get set if the register is initially empty...

Comment: A weakness to using `1L` is that it is signed and shifting a 1 into the sign position is an issue as `CREG_CLK_CTRL_I2C0` could be 31.  Code could use `1UL` to avoid that.